# retrieve columns from sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in sqlite:

```
CREATE TABLE fruit ('fid' integer, 'name' text);
CREATE TABLE basket ('fid1' integer, 'fid2' integer, 'c1' integer, 'c2' integer);
```

basket is supposed to have count c1 of fruit fid1 and c2 of fruit fid2

I created a view fruitbasket;

```
create view fruitbasket as select * from basket inner join fruit a on a.fid=basket.fid1 inner join fruit b on b.fid=basket.fid2;
```

it works (almost) as expected.

When I type

```
pragma table_info(fruitbasket);
```

I get the following output

```
0|fid1|integer|0||0
1|fid2|integer|0||0
2|c1|integer|0||0
3|c2|integer|0||0
4|fid|integer|0||0
5|name|text|0||0
6|fid:1|integer|0||0
7|name:1|text|0||0
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to SELECT name:1. How can I do it other than going back and re-aliasing the columns?

Comment: What language are you using to access the database?  Are you only wanting command line option?

Comment: various ways. Does it make a difference on how to access name:1?

Comment: Why not realias the columns? Why is that solution so bad? You should avoid Select * anyway so this would be a good reason to get rid of it. It would make your code infinitely clearer and avoid the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double-quotes to indicate column names:

```
select "name:1" from fruitbasket;
```

Here's an example:

```
sqlite> insert into fruit values (1,'apple');
sqlite> insert into fruit values (2,'pear');
sqlite> insert into basket values(1,2,3,4);
sqlite> select "name:1" from fruitbasket;
pear
sqlite>
```

Comment: Doug, thank you very much for answering the question I had asked. I really hate it when people try to answer something else I did not ask.

Three cheers for Doug!!!